# Passing parameters of type List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id> to nested CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to nest a CloudFormation template into another by using the `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` resource type. The nested template has a parameter of type `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>`.

Individually, the nested template runs just fine. But when embedding AWS Console says *Encountered unsupported property ELBSubnetList*.

Changing the parameter's type to String/CommaSeparated list seems to be a workaround, as dicussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770088/cloudformation-passing-a-listawsec2subnetid-parameter-as-a-comma-separa) but I'd loose the fancy UI when creating the template interactivly via AWS Console.

Do you have any idea how to pass the list of subnet ids as a paramter?

This is the embedded template:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters" : {
        "ELBSubnetList" : {
            "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
            "Description" : "Subnet List for Elastic Loadbalancer"
        },
        "ELBSecurityGroupList": {
            "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>",
            "Description": "Security Group List for Elastic Loadbalancer"
        }
    },
    "Resources" : {
        "ELB" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties" : {
                "Subnets": { "Ref": "ELBSubnetList" },
                "CrossZone" : "true",
                "SecurityGroups": { "Ref": "ELBSecurityGroupList" },
                "LBCookieStickinessPolicy" : [ {
                    "PolicyName" : "CookieBasedPolicy",
                    "CookieExpirationPeriod" : "30"
                }],
                "Listeners" : [ {
                    "LoadBalancerPort" : "80",
                    "InstancePort" : "80",
                    "Protocol" : "HTTP",
                    "PolicyNames" : [ "CookieBasedPolicy" ]
                } ],
                "HealthCheck" : {
                    "Target" : "HTTP:80/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php",
                    "HealthyThreshold" : "2",
                    "UnhealthyThreshold" : "5",
                    "Interval" : "10",
                    "Timeout" : "5"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the template that embedds:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters": {
        "ChildTemplate": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cf-templates-xxxxxxxxxxx-eu-central-1/sample_child.template"
        },
        "ELBSubnetList" : {
            "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
            "Description" : "Subnet List for Elastic Loadbalancer"
        },
        "ELBSecurityGroupList": {
            "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>",
            "Description": "Security Group List for Elastic Loadbalancer"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "Child": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Properties": {
                "TemplateURL": { "Ref": "ChildTemplate" },
                "Parameters": {
                    "ELBSubnetList": { "Ref": "ELBSubnetList" },
                    "ELBSecurityGroupList": { "Ref": "ELBSecurityGroupList" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to CloudFormation docs this is unsupported, only strings can be passed to nested stacks as of today. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-parameters

Comment: Have you tried hacks with Lambda based Custom Resources?

Comment: @MichalGasek you are right. After fixing the typo in the `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`-Resource the error message becomes much clearer:  _Value of property Parameters must be an object with String (or simple type) properties_

Comment: However, there is no need for Lambda based Custom Resources. In fact, I learned that I'm able to convert a parameter of type `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>` into String by using `{"Fn::Join": [",", { "Ref": "ELBSubnetList" }]}`.

Comment: If requiring just one value from the list, I use (in yaml): `!Select [0, !Ref ELBSubnetList]`, for example...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lists can be converted into Strings and vice versa. So the working invocation is

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters": {
        "ChildTemplate": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cf-templates-xxxxxxxxxxx-eu-central-1/sample_child.template"
        },
        "ELBSubnetList" : {
            "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
            "Description" : "Subnet List for Elastic Loadbalancer"
        },
        "ELBSecurityGroupList": {
            "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>",
            "Description": "Security Group List for Elastic Loadbalancer"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "Child": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Properties": {
                "TemplateURL": { "Ref": "ChildTemplate" },
                "Parameters": {
                    "ELBSubnetList": {"Fn::Join": [",", { "Ref": "ELBSubnetList" }]},
                    "ELBSecurityGroupList": {"Fn::Join": [",", { "Ref": "ELBSecurityGroupList" }]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Thats exactly what I am trying to do but it just won't work. I get my subnets as a parameter list like `Subnets": "List<AWS::...>` but when I try to pass it to a nested stack with `Subnets: !Join [",", [ !Ref Subnets ] ]` (in yaml) CloudFormation breaks with `Template validation error: Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined.` Am I missing something? !Ref Subnets is supposed to be a list, isn't it? Any suggestion welcome

Answer (score 8):

To convert a list of SubnetIds to a list of Strings, use a combination of both [JOIN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) and [SPLIT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html).

**TLDR;**
In YAML, add

```
!Split [',', !Join [',', !Ref SubnetIds]]
```

The full answer is 2 parts.

#### Part 1: JOIN

Here `SubnetIds` is a list of type `Subnet.Id`. `JOIN` will combine all IDs to be
one string. For example, a list of subnet ids `JOIN`ed with `,` as the delimiter will be as follows:

`[abc, def, hij]` => `"abc,def,hij"`.

#### Part 2: SPLIT

Now let's take the output from part 1, and `SPLIT` on the delimiter `,`.

`"abc,def,hij"` => `["abc", "def", "hij"]`

---

Here is an example of my use case with creating a Scheduled Task:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters
  SubnetIds:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
    Description: Select at least two subnets in your selected VPC.

  ScheduleTask:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: !Sub 'Trigger Sitemap Generation according to the specified schedule'
      ScheduleExpression: !Ref CronExpression
      State: ENABLED
      Targets:
      - Id: 'targetId'
        Arn: !GetAtt ECSCluster.Arn
        RoleArn: !GetAtt ECSEventsRole.Arn
        EcsParameters:
          TaskDefinitionArn: !Ref TaskDefinition
          TaskCount: 1
          LaunchType: 'FARGATE'
          PlatformVersion: 'LATEST'
          NetworkConfiguration:
            AwsVpcConfiguration:
              AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
              SecurityGroups:
                - !Ref SecurityGroup
              Subnets: !Split [',', !Join [',', !Ref SubnetIds]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Successfully built in YAML using the following excerpt:

```
Parameters:
  pSubnetIDs:
    Description: The array of Subnet IDs for the Subnet group
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
Resources:
  rDBSubnetGroup:
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
    Properties: 
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: The subnet group for the RDS instance
      SubnetIds: !Ref pSubnetIDs
```

I tried a bunch of variations of !Join and !Ref with no success.  Turns out it is just straightforward !Ref of the list.

Comment: is this the parent or the nested?

Comment: It seems to be the nested template. @molz can you post the parent template?

Answer (score 5):

In YAML you need to "split" the Subnets by using Select. For example with two subnets :

```
!Join [",", [!Select [0, !Ref Subnets], !Select [1, !Ref Subnets]]]
```

Comment: The following would be more elegant - will work with any array size:  !Join [",", !Ref Subnets]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help to another person: but for me works this:

In child template:

```
SubnetIds:
    Description: Choose which subnets should be deployed to
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
```

but in the parent template

```
    SubnetIds:
        Description: Choose which subnets should be deployed to
        Type: CommaDelimitedList
        
        
    Stack:
      Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
      Properties:
        TemplateURL: {s3}
        Parameters:
            SubnetIds: !Join [',', !Ref SubnetIds]
```